# Corona storyboard goback to scene

Tags: lua, coronasdk

I have a timer in my `play.lua` that when it hits 0 it goes automatically to `timeend.lua` which indicates that its time's up. But when I close the scene of `timeend` (by a button) it goes to `menu.lua` but does not function well. When I touch play button in menu it shows nothing but the background.

#### menu.lua

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene ( )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local _X, _Y = display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2

local function playScene(event)
storyboard.gotoScene("easymediumhard", "fade", 100)
helpbutton.isVisible = false
playbutton.isVisible = false
end

local function helpScene(event)
storyboard.gotoScene("help", "fade", 100)
helpbutton.isVisible = false
playbutton.isVisible = false
end

function scene:createScene(event)
end
scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene )

function scene:enterScene(event)
local group = self.view

 --BG
local bg = display.newImage("brownbg.png");
group:insert(bg)
--Logo
local logo = display.newImage("logo.png")
logo.x = 200
logo.y = 70
group:insert(logo)
local brown = display.newImage("bannermenu.png")
brown.y = 350
group:insert(brown)

--Button
playbutton = widget.newButton
{
defaultFile = "playbutton.png",
overFile = "playbuttontouched.png",
onRelease = playScene,
}
playbutton.y = _Y+78
playbutton.x = _W/2

helpbutton = widget.newButton
{
defaultFile = "helpbutton.png",
overFile = "helpbuttontouched.png",
onRelease = helpScene,
}
helpbutton.y = _Y+140
helpbutton.x = _W/2
end
scene:addEventListener ("enterScene",scene) 

function scene:exitScene(event)
end
scene:addEventListener ( "exitScene", scene )

function scene:destroyScene(event)
end
scene:addEventListener ( "destroyScene", scene ) 
return scene
```

#### easymediumhard.lua

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene ( )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local _X, _Y = display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2

local function easyScene(event)
storyboard.gotoScene("play", "fade", 1000)
end

function scene:createScene(event)
end

scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene )

function scene:enterScene(event)
    local group = self.view

 --BG
local bg = display.newImage("brownbg.png");
group:insert(bg)

local brown = display.newImage("bannermenu.png")
brown.y = 250
group:insert(brown)

--Easy Medium Hard text
local easy = display.newImage("easytext.png")
easy:addEventListener ( "touch", easyScene )
easy.x = _W/2
easy.y = 210
group:insert(easy)

local medium = display.newImage("mediumtext.png")
medium.x = _W/2
medium.y = 255
group:insert(medium)

local hard = display.newImage("hardtext.png")
hard.x = _W/2
hard.y = 298
group:insert(hard)

end
scene:addEventListener ("enterScene", scene) 
 function scene:destroyScene(event)

end
scene:addEventListener ( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

#### play.lua

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene ( )
--BG
local bg = display.newImage("brownbg.png");

--TIMES UP  
local function timesupScene()   
storyboard.gotoScene("timeend", "fade", 100)
end

--Timer 
local tmr = 60
local timetext = display.newText("Time: " ,180,10,"Arial",20)
timetext:setTextColor(64,64,64)

local timeleft = display.newText(tmr,250,10,"Impact",21)
timeleft:setTextColor(64,64,64)

local myTimer 

local function countTimer()

tmr = tmr - 1
timeleft.text = tmr

if tmr == 55 then
    timesupScene()
end 
end

myTimer= timer.performWithDelay(2000,countTimer,60)

local function pauseGame()
timer.pause(myTimer)
_paused.isVisible = false
_resume.isVisible = true    
end 

local function resumeGame()
timer.resume(myTimer)
_resume.isVisible = false
_paused.isVisible = true

end

_resume = display.newImage( "playbuttonsmall.png")
_resume.isVisible = false
_resume:addEventListener ( "touch", resumeGame )
_resume.x = 73
_resume.y =30

 _paused = display.newImage( "pausebuttonsmall.png")
_paused:addEventListener ( "touch", pauseGame )
_paused.x = 27
_paused.y=30



function scene:createScene(event)   
end

scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene )

function scene:exitScene(event)
timer.cancel(myTimer)
tmr = 60
timetext:removeSelf();
_resume:removeSelf();
_paused:removeSelf();

end

scene:addEventListener ( "exitScene", scene )

 function scene:destroyScene(event)

end
scene:addEventListener ( "destroyScene", scene )
return scene
```

#### timeend.lua

```
local storyboard = require "storyboard"
local scene = storyboard.newScene ( )
local widget = require( "widget" )
local _W, _H = display.contentWidth/2, display.contentHeight/2

local function closeScene(event)

local previousScene = storyboard.getPrevious()
storyboard.gotoScene("easymediumhard")

return true

end

function scene:createScene(event)
_banner = display.newImage("bannermenu.png")
_banner.isVisible = false
_banner.y =  200

_timesup = display.newImage("timeisuptext.png")
_timesup.isVisible = false
_timesup.y =  210
_timesup.x =165

_closebuttonsmall = display.newImage("closebuttonsmall.png")
_closebuttonsmall.isVisible = false
_closebuttonsmall:addEventListener ( "touch", closeScene )
_closebuttonsmall.y =  _H/2 +180
_closebuttonsmall.x =_W/2+210
end

scene:addEventListener ( "createScene", scene )

function scene:enterScene(event)
_banner.isVisible = true
_timesup.isVisible = true
_closebuttonsmall.isVisible = true
end
scene:addEventListener ("enterScene",scene) 

function scene:exitScene(event)
_banner.isVisible = false
_timesup.isVisible = false
_closebuttonsmall.isVisible = false
end
scene:addEventListener ( "exitScene", scene )

function scene:destroyScene(event)
end
scene:addEventListener ( "destroyScene", scene )

return scene
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure what your problem is but I think I have a good idea, I'm also new to Corona and have run into similar problems.

When working with scenes you need to clear important variables on the `destroyScene` function.  Basically if you don't and come back to the same scene you can have weird problems.  There's also another thing you can do.

Once you get to your next scene you can `removeScene` the previous scene from memory (which will clear all of it).  You could do this in the enterScene function of the next scene.  I implemented a solution that allows for this regardless of what the previous scene is (so it's more dynamic).

When I call the next scene I do something like this:

```
local options = {effect = "fade",800,params={destroy = true,toDestroy = 'scenes.gameOver'}}
storyboard.gotoScene('scenes.mainMenu',options)
```

Then in my next scene on `enterScene` I do a check for the parameter, if it's there then I remove the scene:

```
local params = event.params
--Check for any previous scenes to destroy
if params and params.destroy == true then
    storyboard.removeScene(params.toDestroy)
end
```

This might be along the lines of what you need.

Comment: Hi Fernker! Thanks a bunch! It works on my play game and time's up but after returning closing and returning to menu my objects in play game appears on the menu. ? :(

Comment: Then you probably need to do some clearing on scene exit.  Basically I think there might be some objects not getting cleared in the scene when the new one comes in.   

Another question, are you putting your objects into display groups?  You need to do this for scenes.  And then put all of the display group objects into the scene object.  So you'll probably need to look up some tutorials for how to do that but it's pretty simple.  I learned it over a few weeks with some tutorials and trial and error.

Comment: @Nana if this answered your question then be sure to mark it as the answer.  This will help those looking for a solution in the future.